# Generate a matrix from a row vector and a column vector numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays :

```
    a = [ (0,0,255), (0,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,0,0) ]

    b = [
         (0,0,255),
         (0,0,0),
         (0,255,0),
         (255,0,0)
        ]
```

how can I use numpy to get the following matrix:

```
    [
     [ (0,0,255), (0,0,255), (0,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,0,0) ],
     [ (0,0,0), (0,0,255), (0,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,0,0) ],
     [ (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (0,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,0,0) ],
     [ (255,0,0), (0,0,255), (0,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,0,0) ]
    ]
```

I'm trying to do a pair-wise pixel comparison between all pixels in an image.

Comment: Why is the length of the second axis `5`?

Comment: So, a equals b? What's the catch?

Answer (score 0):

Simple pythonic way:

```
z = [[i] + a for i in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of getting the above matrix which you require using `numpy`

```
In []: a = np.asarray([ (0,0,255), (0,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,0,0) ])
In []: b= np.asarray([(0,0,255), (0,0,0), (0,255,0), (255,0,0)])
In []: np.array([np.vstack((a[i],b)) for i,v in enumerate(a)])
Out[]: 
array([[[  0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]],

       [[  0, 255,   0],
        [  0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]],

       [[255,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0, 255,   0],
        [255,   0,   0]]])
```